# What type of reference does PyModule_GetFilenameObject return?

Tags: python-3.x, python-c-api

`PyModule_GetFilename` was apparently deprecated in version 3.2, with `PyModule_GetFilenameObject` being the suggested replacement. `PyModule_GetFilenameObject` returns a `PyObject*`, but the [Python 3 C API documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/module.html) doesn't specify whether the returned object is a new reference or a borrowed reference. What kind of reference is returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the source, `PyModule_GetFilenameObject` calls `Py_INCREF` on the `PyObject*` it returns immediately before returning, so it appears that the function is returning a new reference.